# Assign JavaScript values to C# Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Javascript function that pulls down variables, like so:

```
   function OnClientCloseSecure(oWnd, args) {
       var arg = args.get_argument();

       if (arg) {
           var ResultCode = arg.ResultCode;
           var PONumber = arg.PONumber;
       }
   }
```

I need to assign ResultCode and PONumber to a variable in C# or if that isn't possible a label in c#.

Are any of these options possible? If so, how would I go about doing that? I've tried several things with no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to create hidden value and set the runat attribute to server. you can get the
value.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   function abc() 
    { 
      var str="value"; 
      document.getElementById("Hidden1").value=str; 
    } 

    </script> 

<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind:

```
    string value = Hidden1.Value;
```

Comment: The following is C# code? string value = Hidden1.Value; how do you define Hidden1? what type is Hidden1?

Comment: You cant reach Hidden1.Value like that.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientCloseSecure(oWnd, args) {
        var arg = args.get_argument();
        if (arg) {
            var ResultCode = arg.ResultCode;
            var PONumber = arg.PONumber;
            document.getElementById('<%=lbl.ClientID %>').innerHTML = ResultCode;
        }
    }

</script>
```

### Mark Up

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ASP.NET MVC you can use:

```
@model ImageModel

<form method="post">
  @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ImageModel,new {@id="varA"})
<button>Click Me</button>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById('varA').value = VarB;
</script>
```

As you can see, we assigned js value using 'id' and now when we post the form, js variable is accesible from the MVC Controller.